# How do I check to see if form inputs(x5) have not been left empty by the user, using JavaScript/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on this code below and have had a stab at writing a IF statement around the code with `//*` .

The `if` statement logic should say 'If all(x5) form input fields are empty then show alert message else do what's between `//*`

The user must modify at least one of the five input fields with a letter or number, for the form to be submitted.

```
$('.submit').live('click', function(){

  // *
  $('.submit').parent().find('form').submit();
  alert('The form has been submitted!');
  // *

});
```

HTML Structure:

```
<div style="margin:50px;">
    <div id="search-prefix">
        <form method="post" action="">
            <input type="text" class="alpha-first default-value" name="" maxlength="1" value="?" />
            <input type="text" class="numeric plate-divide default-value" name="" maxlength="3" value="???" />
            <input type="text" class="alpha default-value" name="" maxlength="1" value="?" />
            <input type="text" class="alpha default-value" name="" maxlength="1" value="?" />
            <input type="text" class="alpha default-value" name="" maxlength="1" value="?" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <span class="btn submit">Search</span>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After looking at some of the answers I had another stab at doing it myself.

My approach was quite simple:

On keyUp if the value of `form input` is a '' empty string or nothing, then add a class to the submit button(which is a `<span class="btn empty-fields">...</span>`). Hence:

```
$('form input').keyup(function () {

    if(!($(this).siblings().andSelf().hasClass('field-error'))){        

        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            $('.btn').addClass('empty-fields').removeClass('no-submit submit');
            $('.error-notify').hide();      
        }
        else{ ...
```

When the user clicks on this element it triggers this response:

```
$('.empty-fields').live('click', function(){
    alert('One field MUST be modified to use Search!')
});
```

Appreciate your effort guys, Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and [`$.trim`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) to determine how many fields have been left empty:

```
$('.submit').live('click', function(){    
    var emptyCount = $(this).closest("form").find("input").filter(function() {
        return $.trim(this.value).length === 0;
    }).length;
    if(emptyCount === 5) {
        alert("all 5 are empty");
    } else {
        $('.submit').parent().find('form').submit();
        alert('The form has been submitted!');
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Karim. I figured it out another way & have posted my solution above

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to concate the values of each input fields together and check the length of the result string.

Answer (score -1):

I use the [jQuery Validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) plugin. Quite fancy.

Comment: I would like to do this myself so I can gain a better understanding of the code behind